# Keeping user logged in after closing application in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to keep user logged in after he closes the game made by Unity. I just want user to enter his username and while he has game installed on his phone he can just enter not having to enter username again and again.

Comment: So save the username?

Comment: Wheres should I save it? How should i do that?

Comment: @danilovict2 you can store in the local storage

Answer (score 0):

With so little information, your question is very difficult to answer.
If I understand, you want to save user information after logged in your game, so the next time the user can auto login.

First solution you can create a variable with `[PlayerPrefs][1]` refere to it in the scripting reference [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).
After you logged the user add this to the end of your script, you will need it later:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("isLogged", "yes");
```

Next, on your main Scene, in you Start:

```
 void Start()
{
    // check if user logged
    if (Logged_in())
    {
        // then start the game, user can play. No need to ask for username again
    }
    else
    {
        // user is not logged, ask to enter username
    }

}
```

Now create the helper method that check if user logged

```
 bool Logged_in()
{
    bool isLogged;
    string  data =  PlayerPrefs.GetString("isLogged");

    if(data == "yes")
    {
        isLogged = true;
    }
    return isLogged;
}
```

Note it not recommended to store sensitive data in PlayerPrefs without encrypt them, you can find many option to do that. Here's [a quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sp-Npft79A) to secure  your PlayerPrefs.